# translating C++ for loop to python

Tags: python, c++

I'm having a little trouble translating C++ to python. The trouble I have is with the boolean statements in the for loop `for (Nbound = 1; Nbound < (Nobs + 1) && B < Beta; Nbound++)` and `for (Ndm = 0;(Ndm < (i + 1) && P3 > (0)) || PP == 0; Ndm++)`. I'm unsure how this would work in python, I don't think python allows boolean statements in a for loop, so I think I would have to call it inside with an IF statement, but I'm not entirely sure. Thanks for your help!

also, I've noticed a lot of empty variables in this code for example, `float PP` is there a way of doing this in python or would I just assign it a value of 0 then change it later?

```
    float Pf = 0; //The complement of Beta
    float B = 0; //Beta
    float P3;
    float PP;
    float Nbound = 1;
    for (Nbound = 1; Nbound < (Nobs + 1) && B < Beta; Nbound++) {
        int Ndm = 0;
        int Nbgd = Nobs; //Setting Ndm=Nobs
        Pf = 0; //Zeroing the placeholder for the sum
        float exp; //A variable to store the exponential
        for (int i = 0; i < (Nobs + 1); i++) //Summing over Nbgd+Ndm<NObs
        {
            P3 = 1;
            PP = 0;
            if (P1[Nbgd] > 0) {

                for (Ndm = 0;(Ndm < (i + 1) && P3 > (0)) || PP == 0; Ndm++) {
                    //P3 = dist(Ndm, Nbound);
                    Pf = Pf + (P1[Nbgd] * P3); //Summing over the probability
                    PP = PP + P3;
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: python does have while loops and any for loop can be transformed to an equivalent while loop

Comment: you could use `for Nbound in range(1, Nobs + 1): if B >= Beta: break`

Comment: Aside: none of `B`, `Beta`, `P3` nor `PP` influence the loop conditions here, so it can be `for Nbound in range(1, Nobs + 1): for i in range(0, Nobs + 1): for Ndm in range(0, i + 1):`

Answer (score 5):

`For` loops in Python are meant for iteration over objects. If you want a loop with specific exit condition then you should use the `while` loop.

`for` loops in C can be described as :

```
for {initialization_statement; condition_expression; update_statement)
{
    body_statement_1;
    body_statement_2;
    ...
    body_statement_n;
}
```

The corresponding loop in Python is :

```
initialization_statement
while condition_expression:
   body_statement_1
   body_statement_2
   ...
   body_statement_n
   update_statement
```

Comment: Aside: The C++ standard [*defines*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/stmt.for#1) a for loop in terms of a while loop (with a slightly special handling of `continue`)

Comment: Thanks Caleth. Interesting point I did not know.